# Product measure without integration

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-integral, product-measure

> **Is it possible to prove the existence of the product measure without the concept of integration?**

*My thoughts* are focused on trying to prove it indirectly using the Carathéodory's extension theorem. The path I'm trying to follow is described bellow:

Let $(\Omega_1,\mathcal{F}_1,\mu_1)$ and $(\Omega_2,\mathcal{F}_2,\mu_2)$ be two measure spaces. If $A\times B\subset\Omega_1\times\Omega_2$ is a **rectangle**, that is, $A\in\mathcal{F}_1$ and $B\in\mathcal{F}_2$ such that $A\times B=\bigoplus_{i=1}^{\infty}A_i\times B_i$ where $A_i\times B_i$ is a rectangle for every $i\in\mathbb{N}$ and $\bigoplus$ stands for disjoint union.

1. Can we always obtain a (potentially **non countable!!**) regular subdivision of $A\times B$. That is, can we always write $A\times B=\bigoplus_{j\in J}\bigoplus_{k\in K}A_j'\times B_k'$, being $A_i'\times B_j'$ rectangles such that $A=\bigoplus_{j\in J}A_j'$, $B=\bigoplus_{k\in K}B_k'$, $A_i=\bigoplus_{j\in J(A_i)} A_j'$ and $B_j=\bigoplus_{k\in K(B_j)} B_k'$.

We just have to consider the family $\mathcal{C}_A:=\{\bigcap A_i\not=\emptyset\}$ (analogously for $B$), then define for every $C\in\mathcal{C}_A$ (analogously for $\mathcal{C}_B$) $C':=\bigcup_{C\not\subset A_i}A_i$, and finally consider $\mathcal{D}_A:=\{C\setminus C':C\in\mathcal{C}_{A}\}$ (analogously for $B$). Then it is easy to prove that the products $A_j\times B_k$ where $A_j\in\mathcal{D}_A$ and $B_k\in\mathcal{D}_{B}$ make up a regular subsivision of $A\times B$.

2. In order to apply Carathéodory's extension theorem we need to prove that if $A\times B=\bigoplus_{i=1}^{\infty}A_i\times B_i$ then $\mu(A\times B)\leq \sum_{i=1}^{\infty}\mu(A_i\times B_i)$ where $\mu$ is the hypothetical product measure. For the finite case we can obtain the equality easily, but for the infinite case **I really don't know what to do when the regular subdivision is non countable**.

I suspect that my last bold remark is the reason why I've never came across with the required proof, but maybe there is some trick that I'm missing...

**Any ideas?**